# What is the correct position of würde in this sentence?

Tags: verb-usage, position

Is würde in the correct position in this sentence:

> Ein Fetzen war über seinen Mund gebunden worden, damit er ihn nicht **würde** schreien hören.

or should it be at the end:

> Ein Fetzen war über seinen Mund gebunden worden, damit er ihn nicht schreien hören **würde**.

And why, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both variants are correct.

No. 1 with 'würde' leading has the upside that it eases comprehension, plus it sounds a bit more poetic at least to my ears.

**Note** however that there is a referrence problem with 'er': as is, this 'er' refers to the same person that 'seinen' does.

Also, 'war gebunden worden' is technically correct, but unusual; 'wurde gebunden' was your choice when simply reporting.
EDIT: I shouldn't call it unusual, rather: wheter 'war gebunden worden' is correct or not depends on the context in which this information is given; namely, is it placed with a review?

Lastly, when replacing 'er' by the person who gagged the poor guy, 'müssen' looks to be the correct modality.

> Ein Fetzen war über seinen Mund gebunden worden, damit der Entführer ihn nicht würde schreien hören müssen.

Comment: "... der Entführer ihn nicht schreien hören müsse". Das 'würde' ist dann überflüssig.

Comment: It may be of interest, that 2 native German speakers, born and educated through university level in Germany, for this English sentence, "and a rag was bound over his mouth so that the troll would not hear him scream," provided the following translation: "und ein Fetzen war über seinen Mund gebunden, damit der Troll ihn nicht würde schreien hören." And they insisted that this was the only correct placement for würde. I can only conclude that German is an exceptionally difficult language to master.

Comment: Did in fact ask about the dismissal of 'worden' as to refer to the state and not the action leading up to that state, conclusion: both are fine. However, we did not have the english original, which may well have influenced your two sources. Also, the modality I suggested with 'müssen' (which is in fact fine despite the veto) would likely not have come up when translating.